# In a LinkedList, what is the difference between : list.add(...) and object.list.add(...)?

Tags: java, linked-list

Im doing some assignments and in one exercise, we have to copy paste this :

```
class Example
{
    LinkedList<String> queue;

    //Some simple methods to add or remove from queue.

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Example obj = new Example();
        obj.queue = new LinkedList<String>();

        //Basic instructions to add items to the queue
    }
}
```

But this confuses me, we were creating and filling Lists like this :

```
LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();

queue.add("abc");
queue.add("bca");
```

And now we have to create it like

```
Example obj = new Example();
obj.queue = new LinkedList<String>();
```

And i wonder if if there is any difference between :

```
obj.queue.add("aab");
```

and
    queue.add("aab);

I know this is really basic, but i lack some basic concepts and im pretty lost with this.

Thank you.

Comment: I recommend searching about the `static` keyword. This question has nothing to do with Linked Lists.

Comment: @Mephy Does it have anything to do with `static`?

Comment: search for local variable and class field

Comment: There is a need to create an object of class `Example` because the method (`main`) is static and the queue object is an instance name. So yeah, if main wasn't static, the instance of Example wouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,

```
LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();

queue.add("abc");
queue.add("bca");
```

you are creating a new `LinkedList` object whose reference you are assigning to the variable `queue`. You then dereference `queue` so that you can invoked its method `add`.

Here

```
Example obj = new Example();
obj.queue = new LinkedList<String>();
obj.queue.add("bca");
```

you are creating a new object of type `Example` and assigning its reference to the variable `obj`. You then dereference `obj` to access its field `queue` to which you assign the reference of the newly created `LinkedList` object. You then dereference `obj` again to access the field `queue` whose value you dereference so that you can invoke `add` on the referenced `LinkedList` object.

Consider reading through the Java tutorial on [Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you delcared a LinkedList named "queue" directly inside a method, e.g. main(),
the variable queue would be considered a local variable.

On the other hand, if the variable is a part of a class, e.g. "class Example",
it's considered a member of the class, suppose the visibility of the queue is public or at package level, you have access the variable through the class reference.

If my explanations aren't clear enough,
I believe the following links should solve your problem.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 1):

```
LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
queue.add("abc");
queue.add("bca");
```

You create a `LinkedList` instance called queue and you add "abc" ,"bca" to this list queue;

```
Example obj = new Example();
obj.queue = new LinkedList<String>();
obj.queue.add("bca");
```

You class `Example` now have a reference of a `LinkedList` called queue, for example, a house has a door, now you can  painting on this door, but the door belongs to the house and when the house is destroyed, the door will be also destroyed.

But in your first case is that, you have a door, but this door does not belong to any house.It is independent.

For good practice in your case, you should construct your door in one method(like constructors), and try not to directly give your door to your neighbor unless it is needed to be do that out of the control your house. :)

```
public class Example {
        private LinkedList<String> queue;// private, and no outside class can get access to it

        public Example(){
            this.queue= new LinkedList<String>();//construct the queue when you Example is constructed
        }

        public void add(String s){// add element in the control of Example 
            queue.add(s);
        }
        //Some simple methods to add or remove from queue.
        public static void main(String[]args)
        {
            Example obj = new Example();
            obj.add("abc");
            obj.add("cba");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That Door example really helped me :D